# Scala Implicit Parameters Projection Conflict , "Ambigious Implicit Values" Error

Tags: scala, implicit

I have been reading Bruno's TypeClasses paper and he mentioned that implicits in the argument list are projected/propagated into the implicit scope.  I followed the example with this code:

```
package theory

import cats.implicits.toShow

import java.io.PrintStream
import java.util.Date

object Equality extends App {
  import cats.Eq

//  assert(123 == "123")
  println(Eq.eqv(123, 123).show)

  implicit val out: PrintStream = System.out

  def log(m: String)(implicit o: PrintStream ): Unit =
    o.println(m)

  def logTime(m: String)(implicit  o: PrintStream): Unit =
    log(s"${new Date().getTime} : $m")

}
```

The kicker is that this code will *not compile*, with:

```
ambiguous implicit values:
 both value out in object Equality of type java.io.PrintStream
 and value o of type java.io.PrintStream
 match expected type java.io.PrintStream
    log(s"${new Date().getTime} : $m")
```

So, I assume that the compiler sees 2 instances of the same implicit and complains.  I was able to silence the compiler by explicitly adding the PrintStream passed as an argument as the second argument to log:

```
def logTime(m: String)(implicit  o: PrintStream): Unit =
    log(s"${new Date().getTime} : $m")(o)
```

This works, but am I missing something?  Why is there confusion inside the body of logTime()?  I thought Bruno was implying that the implicit from the caller would be projected into the scope of the method.  His example *does not* add the extra parameter to the log() call.  Why does scalac see these as 2?  I suppose I assumed that the implicit from the outer method would "hide" the val out.  Not so.

If anyone can explain why I see this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Inside `logTime` there are two valid instances of an implicit value of type `PrintStream` _(a terrible type to be implicit btw)_ which makes it ambiguous, which is a compile error; period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the value of an implicit parameter is determined at the call site. That's why...

```
Equality.log("log this")
```

...won't compile unless an implicit value of the appropriate type is brought into scope.

```
implicit val ps: PrintStream = ...
Equality.log("log this")
```

The `logTime()` definition code is a call site for the `log()` method and, since it is defined within the `Equality` object, it has the `implicit val out` value available to it. But it is also the recipient of the `implicit o` value of the same type that was passed from its call site. Thus the ambiguity. Should the compiler send the `implicit out` value or the `implicit o` value to the `log()` method?

Now, it might seem a bit odd that the received implicit value (from the call site) is both assigned to a local identifier, `o`, *and* inserted into the local implicit namespace as well. It turns out that Scala-3 has modified that behavior and your code compiles without error, even without the new `given`/`using` syntax. (I assume the `implicit out` value is passed to the `log()` method and not the received `o` value.)

Comment: Based on your keen eye, I refactored and removed the implicit val from the Equality object, and BAM!  Now it compiles & works as planned!  Thank you for the help!!!